# How do you play custom music on the radio?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas, fallout-3

How do you play custom music on the radio in Fallout 3 and/or Fallout: New Vegas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember using [this mod](http://www.fallout3nexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=145) some time ago and it worked. Can't recall how much of a hassle it was to set up though.

Comment: I suppose it should work for Fallout 3. But I'm actually more interested in New Vegas at the moment. Thanks for direction found what I was looking for here: http://newvegasnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=35061

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but something that might help.

You can download a [Mod Manager](http://www.fallout3nexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=640) from Fallout 3 Nexus which is compatible with both Fallout 3 and Fallout New Vegas.

This will assist in the installation and management of mods.